# Trying to sum a column of values between settable dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a list of costs over a period of time.  Each row is a date, descriptor, quantity and value.  So looking at the image, all the values in B, C and D are entered manually or through some other means.  What I want is, at any given time, to go into the sheet, and insert in B14 and B15, the start and stop dates for the range I need subtotaled.
So I go in and enter 2/10 (B14) and 5/1 (B15) and the following formulas calculate:

- B16: the total # of rows included in the new range
- C16: the sum of C within the new range
- D16: the average cost of the items in D within the new range
- E16: the total cost (sum) of E within the new range

I know how to do EVERYTHING except for how to establish the range by being able to enter a couple of dates.  Those things are really simple, basic, Excel things.  But this custom field-value driven range is killing me.

Any ideas?  Thank you so much!

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nrf09oWbhY37xMwoGaviyOWkaP-tXyafOEVqlDS9vSg/edit?usp=sharing) is a public-viewable Google doc since I could not post a pic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B16 is fairly easy: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6, ">"&$B$14, $A$1:$A$6, "<"&$B$15)`. 
(Assuming that you have 6 rows of data.)

C16 is a little trickier:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$6>$B$14), --($A$1:$A$6<$B$15), $C$1:$C$6)
```

You can figure out D16 and E16 now, right?

Comment: Wow, ok... that was much simpler than I realizes.  Thanks so much.  This was a good solve.  Yes, I was easily able to transpose it to the other cells.